# Do we need to format the date when we declare a date object in Swift language and Realm database?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am changing a property of `nextDate` from data type string to type `Date()` in my IOS application. I am using Realm as my database. I've made the change to the property in the object class `CasesClassFinal` swift file. I've also made changes to the other part of the application to accommodate this change including converting string to date (such as when accepting date input from user) and date to string (such as displaying date on labels in the app) whenever and wherever required. When I clicked the run button the build succeeded and my app simulator appeared. However when I logged into the app the app crashed. In the console it was stated :

> 2019-01-17 12:14:25.534909+0800 MyCases[1769:15719] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type date for property 'nextDate' on object of type 'CasesClassFinal', but received: 17/01/2019'

I was wondering maybe that console message is stating that the format used in my application i.e. dd/MM/yyyy is different from the `nextDate` property format. When I declared `nextDate` the code I've used:

```
@objc dynamic var nextDate = Date()
```

If that is the case how would I declare the `nextDate` property so it conforms to the dd/MM/yyyy format I am using.

Or is it a different problem altogether?

I’m still testing the app. Just found out even when I’ve set the date format to 18/01/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy) when saving the date from the datepicker, what appeared in the realm file is different. In Realm database in the nextDate property it is in the format "18 Jan 2019 at 12:00:00 AM". Maybe this info would help. I was only able to add data when I set the “Is Initial View Controller” to the data entry page. The app did not crash when I do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure, **17/01/2019** is not in string format.

Comment: User will give date input using DatePicker in a textfield. The date is converted from string to date type when saving the data entered. So I am sure 17/01/2019 is of date type and not string.

Comment: And thinking of it I’m not sure where did the 17/01/2019 comes from. Like I said earlier the app crashed even before I could enter any data into the app (besides my log in data).